# How do I push state in an array in reducer using createReducer and combineReducer

Tags: angular, ngrx

Please I am having problem creating the profile and reducer. I want to push profile into array and be able to use it in the combine reducer. There is no error but it's not displaying anything in redux tool.

```
export const profileReducer = createReducer(
    initialState.student.details.profile,
    on(updateProfile, (state,{ profile} ): any => state.push(profile)),
    
);

export const gradeReducer = createReducer(
initialState.student.details.grades,
  on(upgradeGrade, (state, { grades }): any => grade
        
)


export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   profile: profileReducer,
   grades: gradeReducer
})
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to create a combine reducer with the profileReducer and gradeReducer.

Thank you

Comment: Try something like this -  on(updateProfile, (state, { grades }) => ({ profile: [...profile, grades]  }))

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of the reducers is not clear in the question, but I can guess.
The idea is you can put them both in one Reducer like:

```
export const profileReducer = createReducer(
  initialState.student.details,
  on(updateProfile, (state,{ profile} ): any => state.profile.push(profile)),
  on(upgradeGrade, (state, { grades }): any => state.grades = grades),  
);
```

Or

```
export const profileReducer = createReducer(
  initialState.student.details,
  on(updateProfile, (state,{ profile} ) => { 
    return {...state, profile.push(profile) } 
  }),
  on(upgradeGrade, (state, { grades }) => {
    return { ...state, grades : grades }
  }),  
);
```